# Как передать URL страницы с параметрами?

Tags: php

Есть форма. Нужно отправить вместе со всеми данными и УРЛ страницы.
Передаю при помощи такого кода:

```
http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]
```

Но у меня ссылка с параметрами: `site.com/form/index.html?ref=https://...`.
В ней передается еще ссылка на видео, с которого был переход на эту форму, и вот эта самая нужная часть не передается. Я получаю только ссылку вида `site.com/form`.

Comment: Параметры должны пройти escape или html-encode. Символы пробел /\%& должны принять другие значения, чаще всего вида %3D.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример, где все передается:

```
<form action="/" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="url" value="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

И далее получаете то, что передали:

```
$url = $_REQUEST['url'];
```